# Disabling some characters with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm having an issue with my register page, **i noticed that people can register with alt codes like this "ªµµª"** and i tried to fix it by using preg_replace but when i did that i couldn't register anymore, atleast not with the worldwide alphabet

```
    final public function validName($username)  
{
    if(strlen($username) <= 25 && ctype_alnum($username))   
    {           
        return true;        
    }               

    return false;   
}
```

Tried to fix it by replacing it with this

```
if(strlen($username) <= 25 && preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", $username))
```

But i'm obviously doing something wrong...

Comment: You're allowing users to have numerical values in their _names_ as they register?

Comment: Yeah, as i want people to only use letters and numbers, but in my case they can register with ªµµª ªªªª and things like that, which i don't want them to.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: `var_dump(ctype_alnum("ªµµª"));` returns `false` as expected. Using a regex seems useless. Perhaps the problem is elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you are confusing two different uses of the caret (^) metacharacter.

Indeed, it may be two things in a regular expression:

- It may assert the start of the subject, which is what you probably want.
- It may negate the class, which is what you're doing in your code.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php

Here is a modified version of your code, with the caret (^) and dollar ($) signs to assert the start and the end of the strings you're analyzing:

```
function validName($username)  
{
    if (strlen($username) <= 25 && preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $username))   
    {           
        return true;        
    }               

    return false;   
}     

$names = array(
  'Abc1',
  'Abc$',
  "ªµµª"
);

foreach ($names as $name) {
  echo "<br>" . $name . ': ' . (validName($name) ? 'valid' : 'invalid');
}

// -- Returns: 
// Abc1: valid
// Abc$: invalid
// ªµµª: invalid
```

Note that you may reduce the code inside your function to one line:

```
function validName($username)  
{
    return strlen($username) <= 25 && preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $username);
}
```